# Video Conferência no Navegador

Tags: javascript, html5, vídeo, streaming

preciso desenvolver um sistema de video conferência para rodar em navegadores, até o momento descobri vários provedores de streaming de video, mas não é o que preciso, preciso de qualquer dica sobre o assunto, para que posso me auxiliar a desenvolver uma ferramenta de video conferencia no navegador.

Comment: [WebRTC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) é o que você procura.